# The value of the loop counter of a for loop is one larger than I expect after exit from the loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a simple `for` loop, which lets the loop counter, `i` go up to 5.

```
 int i;
 double n = 1 / 2; 
 for (i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
    n = n + 1.0 / i; 
 }
 System.out.print(i);
```

So I expect the value of the counter to be 5 after the loop finishes. But the value is 6, nit 5. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: Because there is an `i++` at the end? Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Also, `double n = 1 / 2;` becomes 0 and not 0.5 because you are doing integer divisions. To make it 0.5 you have to write `1.0 / 2.0` (at least one number has to be double).

Comment: `i` is increased until the condition in the for loop is not true anymore. `5 <= 5` is true but `6 <= 5` is false. Therefore, it stops.

Comment: because that's the way loops are designed. Perhaps read the fine manual?

Comment: Try to follow this guidance before you ask: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 2):

Because you are incrementing i value as `i++` in `for{..}` loop

```
for (i = 2; i <= 5; i++)
                     ^ here
```

In for loop after checking the condition, body part will be executed

after that increment or decrement will be done

**Process will be**

```
               <----
     1step  2step  4step
for (i = 2; i <= 5; i++){
  /*body part*/
   3step
}
```

After 4th step it will moves to check 2nd step i.e. condition part

So thats why it prints the `i` value as

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop:

```
for (i = 2; i <= 5; i++) {
    // code
```

}

which has condition `i <= 5` and the condition will be `false` when `i = 6` and the loop breaks, goes to the print line.

**Thanks for reminding me my first time programming experience, When I used to write a code `a = 5` and printed it to see what it shows in the console. :)**

Answer (score 0):

The `i++` is the same as saying `i = i + 1`. In this case you can also use `++i` and get the same result.